# Cross-interface contracts

Tags: c#, oop, interface, documentation, design-by-contract

I consider interfaces not only as a set of members, but also as a "contract" which force realisation to hold restrictions specified in interface documentation. For example:

```
interface IDevice
{
    bool IsActive { get; }

    int Address { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when (IsActive == false)
    /// and device was activated
    /// </summary>
    event Action Activated;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when (IsActive == true)
    /// and device was deactivated
    /// </summary>
    event Action Deactivated;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when (IsActive == false)
    /// and Address was changed
    /// </summary>
    event Action<int> AddressChanged;
}
```

Also I have users which are not interested in activation/deactivation process but want to know when `Address` will change, so, lead by ISP, I create a new interface:

```
interface IAddressee
{
    int Address { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when Address was changed
    /// </summary>
    event Action<int> AddressChanged;
}
```

And now `IDevice` looks like:

```
interface IDevice : IAddressee
{
    bool IsActive { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when (IsActive == false)
    /// and device was activated
    /// </summary>
    event Action Activated;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when (IsActive == true)
    /// and device was deactivated
    /// </summary>
    event Action Deactivated;
}
```

As you see, `IDevice`'s contract has loosed one condition: `AddressChanged` event should be raised only when device is not active (`IsActive == false`).

I cannot document it in `IAddressee` interface since it is not depend on `IDevice` and non-device implementations can exist.

Is this situation is normal? What would you do to force `IDevice` realisation to correct behaviour?

I am new to the concept of contracts, so please dispel my illusions and doubts

Comment: Are you just asking how to comment the interfaces so someone knows how they work?  Reason I ask is because you haven't lost anything other than the comment about the special conditions for AddressChanged for IDevices.  There is nothing in either case to "force" an implementation to act as you require.  But perhaps you could have a "Debug.Assert(!sender is IDevice || sender.IsActive)" in your AddressChanged event handler.

Comment: Well, commenting is the only way to tell realisation about contract, so yes, I'm asking how to comment it. But also I want to know if I think about it in the right way. Changing all handlers is a bad idea, I think.

Comment: I think the answer to "how do I comment this?" is really subjective.  I guess I would put the comments close to the IDevice declaration, since the ": IAddressee" is the relevant part.  But, do you actually anticipate having objects that implement IAddressee and not IDevice?  If you don't, I would think leaving IDevice as it was is better, anyway.  Your IDevice listeners don't have to register handlers for Activated/Deactivated.  Put another way, I don't think you've gained anything by factoring out AddressChanged unless you have non-IDevice objects that implement IAddressee.

Comment: The example uses condition `IsActive == false` and the discussion after the example uses its inverse `IsActive == true`. One of them may need to be corrected.

Comment: @Aaron yes, "non-device implementations can exist". Even if not, clients should not depend on members they do not use (ISP).

Comment: @astef How does adding members to an interface introduce any dependency into an existing client of that interface?

Comment: @Aaron Client depends on each member it have access to. Even if it does not use one of the members - you can not rely on that without unit-testing. While unit-testing, "not using" is the kind of "using in a correct way"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases abstract conditions will do. They express something that may depend on information not available in the top-level class. The condition is later implemented in a way suitable for a specific descendant. In your example

```
interface IAddressee
{
    int Address { get; }

   /// <summary>
   /// Can Address be changed?
   /// </summary>
   bool IsAddessChangeable { get; };

    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when (IsAddessChangeable == true)
    /// and Address was changed
    /// </summary>
    event Action<int> AddressChanged;
}
```

In a class that implements `IDevice`, the query `IsAddessChangeable` will return `IsActive == false`, in other classes - the value depending on the required semantics.

Comment: At first, I thought this violates ISP because `IAddressee` must depend on member it not use: `IsAddessChangeable`. But then I've changed all events to methods and everything becomes clear. `IAddressee` user really depends on `IsAddessChangeable` due to `AddressChanged` contract. I propose you to extend your answer with example with events replaced with methods (see edits)

Comment: @astef I rolled back your edit, since it was a significant change of the code in the accepted answer. I would recommend you seek feedback from the author about your edit first or post a separate answer.